# Methods for accessing PHP global variables

Tags: php, syntax

`$GLOBALS['current_view']` and `global $current_view`, which do you prefer and why?

Comment: I think you should be asking *what is best practice* as opposed to what people refer (even though they might be the same thing).

Comment: @alex There are actually slight differences.

Comment: @Artefacto Yes, but I'd rather code to best practice then what someone on the Internet *prefers*.

Answer (score 10):

Neither, pass parameters into the methods. Every time you use globals, God kills a kitten.

Answer (score 3):

If I must use globals, and I avoid them like the plague, I use global $current_view. I just prefer to always have a locally scoped variable rather than relying on super globals. But I think its a matter of preference.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I prefer the `$GLOBALS['glob']` syntax because I can just copy paste the code without having to worry about declaring variables as globals. Keep in mind that you should try to keep globals to a minimum (maybe just global configuration directives, and even there...).

However, the two methods are not exactly synonymous; there's a slight difference:

```
function func() {
    var_dump($GLOBALS['glob']);
}

function func2() {
    global $glob;
    var_dump($glob);
}
```

The first one will emit a notice if the global 'glob' does not exist. The second one won't.

In the first case, sending `$GLOBALS['glob']` as an argument compiles to:

```
     3      FETCH_R                      global              $0      'GLOBALS'
     4      FETCH_DIM_R                                      $1      $0, 'glob'
```

You're fetching `GLOBALS` and its index `glob` in a read context; no variable is created.

The second one compiles to

```
     compiled vars:  !0 = $glob
     ...
     2      FETCH_W                      global lock         $0      'glob'
     3      ASSIGN_REF                                               !0, $0
```

You are creating a reference to the global `glob`, so it is implicitly created if it doesn't exist.

Also:

```
function func_unset() {
    unset($GLOBALS['glob']);
}

function func2_unset() {
    global $glob;
    unset($glob);
}
```

The function `func()` will actually unset the global, `func2_unset` will merely destroy the reference that was created.

Note that `func2` is very similar to:

```
function func3() {
    $glob =& $GLOBALS['glob'];
}
```

This one is however potentially less efficient. It compiles to

```
     2      FETCH_W                      global              $0      'GLOBALS'
     3      FETCH_DIM_W                                      $1      $0, 'glob'
     4      ASSIGN_REF                                               !0, $1
```

Answer (score 0):

static classes ftw

```
class View {
    private static $current = null;
    public static function get_current() {
        return self::$current;
    }
}
```